# Hyperref levels are embedded, aren't being reset

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

I'm using the hyperref package with a custom class, and I'm having a problem with hyperref not creating the tree correctly. What I expect to see is this:

```
+ Section 1
++ Section 1.1
++ Section 1.2
+++ Section 1.2.1
+++ Section 1.2.2
++ Section 1.3
+ Section 2
++ Section 2.1
```

But what I'm seeing instead is this:

```
+ Section 1
++ Section 1.1
++ Section 1.2
+++ Section 1.2.1
+++ Section 1.2.2
++++ Section 1.3
+++++ Section 2
++++++ Section 2.1
```

I am guessing there is some kind of level counter that keeps track of what level of section, subsection, subsubsection, etc. the tree is on, and this just isn't being reset when I run `\clearpage` or when I create a chapter or section header.  But I don't know how to reset it, and I don't know what kind of mechanism hyperref uses to keep track of this.  I've been unable to figure out how hyperref does this on my own.

How can I control hyperref's level "counter" from the Latex class level?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Off the cuff, I would imagine `hyperref` uses the counter `secnumdepth` to identify the indentation/level of the section. I'm guessing your 'custom class' has a `\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}` somewhere in the `\section{...}` and `\subsection{...}` definition. Perhaps even a conditional increment since some of the `section`/`subsection`s are at the same level.

Comment: @user463213: Try adding `\usepackage{etoolbox} \pretocmd{\section}{\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{-1}}{}{} \pretocmd{\subsection}{\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{-1}}{}{}` to your preamble to drop the `secnumdepth` counter by one and revert your documentclass changes.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely culprit here is the "custom class" that redefines the way sections are typeset. Specifically, there could be an *increase* in `secnumdepth` rather that *setting* it explicitly. Your choices are:

- either edit the custom document class and fix this `\addtocounter` problem by removing it, and replacing it with the correct, fixed, `secnumdepth`. For example, in the `\section` command, use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`. In `\subsection`, remove `\addtocounter` and use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`. In `\subsubsection`, remove `\addtocounter` and use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}`. This will ensure that the respective sectioning command sit at different levels.
- Use the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to prepend a single drop in the required counter before expanding as usual. That is, by adding

  ```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
  ...
  \pretocmd{\section}{\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{-1}{}{}%
  \pretocmd{\subsection}{\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{-1}{}{}%
  \pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{-1}{}{}%
  ```